# How to output > symbol in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to display a `>` symbol in T-SQL query but I can't.

```
DECLARE @start AS TABLE 
                  (
                      nm varchar(10), 
                      plc varchar(10), 
                      account varchar(10)
                  )

INSERT INTO @start
    SELECT nm, plc,account
    FROM
        (VALUES 
            ('steve', 'toronto', ''),
            ('steve', 'sydney', 'ac1'),
            ('mac', 'new york', 'ac2'),
            ('mac', 'boston', 'ac3'),
            ('mac', 'padderborn', 'ac3')
        ) t2 (nm, plc, account)

SELECT DISTINCT (a.nm),
    STUFF ((SELECT '>' + plc FROM @start b 
            WHERE b.nm = a.nm 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS plc,
    STUFF ((SELECT '>' + account FROM @start b 
            WHERE b.nm = a.nm 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS account
FROM
    @start a
```

I get this result:

[image: Result]

My desired output is following

| nm | plc | account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mac | new york,boston,padderborn | ac2>ac3>ac3 |
| steve | toronto,sydney | >ac1 |

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  nm
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(plc AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @start 
         WHERE nm = T.nm
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') plc
       ,STUFF((SELECT '> ' + CAST(account AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @start 
         WHERE nm = T.nm
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') account
FROM @start T
GROUP BY nm
```

Output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to achieve this if you are using SQL Server 2017 (14.x) or a later version:

```
select a.nm
,string_agg(plc,',') plc
,string_agg(account,'>') account
from 
@start a
group by nm
```

Performance Enhancements: Distinct, STUFF and Subquery are removed.

Comment: [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is available from `SQL Server 2017` onwards